# Mutual possession with "each other"

Tags: grammar

If there are two parties and each person is in possession of something belonging to the other, how do you express this in a sentence? For example, if we give them names, we can say:

> Alice is driving Bob's car, and Bob is driving Alice's car.

Is it proper to say this?

> They are driving each other's cars.

I'm mostly asking because this is how I would probably say it in conversation (as a native speaker in the Midwest), but when I type it out it's suggested as a typo, and now it feels kind of weird thinking about it.

Comment: You have it right, except "*each other*" is two words, not one.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should certainly have a space between *each* and *other*; these are two words. There is no such English word as *eachother*. But if that correction is made, the sentence “They are driving each other’s cars” is perfectly fine. Consider “They are at each other’s throats” as an analogy.

If the given sentence seems too awkward when written out, however, consider “Each of them is driving the other’s car” as an alternative.

Answer (score 1):

If they **each have a car**, then you MUST say: drive **each other's cars.**

If they **only have one car** between them, then you MUST say: drive **each other's car.**

Look here: https://dictionary.cambridge.org/grammar/british-grammar/pronouns/each-other-one-another

Lisa and Kate hated **each other’s husbands.** (Lisa hated Kate’s husband and Kate hated Lisa’s husband.) I hold your hand, you hold my hand. We hold **each other's hands.**

Comment: If they only have one car between them, they can't drive each other's car, no matter whether you pluralize *car* or not.

Comment: C'mon, Mate! Does it really need to be spelled out? They don't have to drive that one car at the same time. They share the use of the same vehicle. Nobody said "they both are driving (the same) car, at the same time".

Answer (score 0):

The correct sentence is:  They are driving each other's car -- not cars (plural).  Whenever you use "each" the object becomes singular, not plural.  Each person only has one car.  Notice that you wrote:  each other's cars -- and not, each others' cars.  So you would have to be wrong because each person only has one car.

If you mean that each person has two or more cars, and they both drive all of the other person's cars, then you can use your original sentence.

Comment: Each other's car, means "one car that belongs to both of them", and they cannot possibly be driving the same car at the same time. So, ONLY plural is to be used. Please check https://dictionary.cambridge.org/grammar/british-grammar/pronouns/each-other-one-another

Comment: Ngrams shows [both plural and singular](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=each+other%27s+throat%2Ceach+other%27s+throats%2Ceach+other%27s+houses%2Ceach+other%27s+house&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Ceach%20other%20%27s%20throat%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Ceach%20other%20%27s%20throats%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Ceach%20other%20%27s%20houses%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Ceach%20other%20%27s%20house%3B%2Cc0) are actually used, but plural dominates (I'm assuming that people don't generally have more than one house or one throat).